# When working with a technology node (say 14nm), should I keep the gate lengths of the FETs strictly equal to the minimum gate length?

Tags: vlsi

When doing simulations with a technology node, say 14nm, can I change the gate lengths of FETs as per my wish?
If I need a FET with 140nm gate length, should I set the gate length of the transistor model to 140nm or should I connect ten 14nm FETs in series?
What is the common practice in VLSI industry regarding this problem?

Comment: The quesiton "will there be a difference between one large and ten series FETs" betrays that you really need to go back and learn your basics. Not even on VLSI, but on basic semiconductors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analog IC designer here.  There are many reasons to use long channel devices, yes.  Here are a few:

1. Leakage.  Especially at smaller process nodes, leakage when the VGS of a MOSFET is 0V can be huge.  If you're designing for a low power device, or if you need the drain of a FET not to influence the node it's touching while the device is off, you use a longer channel device.  This helps to a point, especially the difference between min channel length and 2 or 3 times that.
2. Lower Gm.  Sometimes, you want a lower transconductance in a FET, e.g. for a current mirror.
3. Higher voltage threshold.  Threshold voltage is a strong function of W and L, and if you want a device to have a higher VThr, for example to set a voltage threshold for a single-ended comparator, you must grow your L.
4. Better output impedance.  Minimum channel devices have comparatively low ro (e.g. worse Early voltage) compared to long channel device.  In simple terms, this is because changes to the drain voltage have a bigger effect on the channel.
5. Grow the area for matching reasons.  Transistors have some random offset in their threshold voltage, which is why a differential amplifier with huge input FETs will typically have much lower offset than one with tiny FETs.  This random offset is proportional to 1/sqrt(W*L), so a 2W*2L device will have half the random offset than one with W*L.  For long channel devices, these two transistors are otherwise approximately similar in DC characteristics.
6. Capacitance.  Sometimes, we use MOSFETs as capacitors. In this case, you want the area to be large, and generally the most efficient way to do this is with a relatively large W and L, to improve packing density.

There are other reasons I haven't mentioned; this is off the top of my head.  If it wasn't useful, they wouldn't give it as an option.